# Acesso a url externa no Windows Server

Tags: iis

bom o problema que tenho é o seguinte: Tenho uma aplicação que envia SMS, a mesma faz uma requisição POST a uma determinada url. O que acontece é que executo a aplicação no servidor e ela funciona e consequentemente para os clientes também. Porém depois de cerca de 20 minutos apresenta o erro: "Conexão fechada inesperadamente",  quando abro o browser no servidor ele me pede a credencial e quando coloco ele volta a funcionar e mais uma vez depois de cerca de 20 minutos apresenta o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

Você provavelmente vai ter que usar códigos adicionais para automaticamente inserir suas credenciais no servidor.

Segue alguns sites para que você de uma lida, no primeiro ele fala sobre a Administração das credenciais de autenticação e mostra linhas de código sobre como o implementar (C#)(VB.NET)(JavaScript)(VBSCRIPT)

[Link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/management/authentication/credentials)

E aqui o autor mostra como ele faz para manter seu Wordpress rodando inserindo apenas uma vez suas credenciais

[Link](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/05/04/Wordpress-auto-sign-on-with-IIS7-and-a-plugin.aspx)